# Evento javascript para scroll sobre uma área ou div

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Eu tenho uma pagina onde uma área ou div que não possui a Scrollbar lateral, simplesmente por que não é necessário.Eu gostaria de capturar o evento quando o mouse rotaciona a roleta sobre aquela area, pois queria utilizar a roleta do mouse para Zoom, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viva,

Use o *".on"* para apanhar o evento. Na verdade são dois eventos, para funcionar nos diferentes navegadores.. *"DOMMouseScroll mousewheel"*

```
$('#div').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function ( event ) {
  if( event.originalEvent.detail > 0 || event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 ) {
    console.log('Para baixo');
  } else {
    console.log('Para cima');
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: funcionou muito bem

Answer (score 1):

Amigo. Tem um comando para somente passar o mouse par dar o zoom em imagem. Como vc não colocou código.

Segue:

```
<script language="javascript">
 <!--
  function aumenta(obj){
obj.height=obj.height*2;
obj.width=obj.width*2;
   }

  function diminui(obj){
obj.height=obj.height/2;
obj.width=obj.width/2;
  }
    </script>
```

Html:

```
    <p><img src="IMAGEM" width='258' height='45' alt="img" onMouseOver="aumenta(this)" onMouseOut="diminui(this)">
```

Comment: Muito obrigado também, mas estou usando um plugin terceiro para realizar o zoom diferenciado, só precisava do evento mesmo. Mas também ajudou!

Comment: Parabéns ao Fabio pela resposta. Muito boa. Não conhecia.  Vou salvar aqui também. Kkk